# How to use ImpersonatedUser in neo4j ogm session

Tags: neo4j-ogm

We can use ImpersonatedUser at the time of using neo4j java driver like below:

```
Session session = neo4jDriver.session(SessionConfig.builder().withDatabase(neo4jDB).withImpersonatedUser(userName).build());
```

But how can we use the same at the time of neo4j ogm session in java:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Expectation is to load or run cypherQuery through neo4j ogm session with impersonatedUser in java.